# Strange behavior for filtering in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I've stumbled upon weird data table `i` behavior that returns a row with `NA`s where I would expect an empty data table. See:

```
a = data.table(a = 1, d = NA) 
a[!is.na(a) & d == "3"] 
#     a  d
# 1: NA NA
```

I would expect an empty data table as a result here.
Compare to:

```
a = data.table(a = c(1,2), d = c(NA,3))
a[!is.na(a) & d == "3"] 
#    a d
# 1: 2 3
```

This one does not produce an extra row with `NA` values, though.
Is this a bug in `data.table` or there's some logic underlying this behavior that someone could explain?

Comment: I'm on R 2.15.2 and data.table 1.9.4, if that matters

Comment: It's a bug. Please file an issue on the github project page. Thanks.

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1252). What should be done with this question?

Comment: Better to leave it as such so that we can answer it once fixed, which'll prevent future Q (and is easy to mark as dup if asked).

Comment: @Arun, looks like it has been fixed in 1.9.8. Could you provide an answer with confirmation that this is no longer reproducible so that I could accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the ping @SergiiZaskaleta. I forgot to update this question, but this has been fixed a while ago, [with this commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/353cf8af56db5e604fc4b366acc2e9b61d35da47).

From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> 42. Subsets using logical expressions in `i` never returns all-`NA` rows. Edge case `DT[NA]` is now fixed, [#1252](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1252). Thanks to @sergiizaskaleta.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's a bug or not, but it seems it has to do with the type of your variable d.

```
a = data.table(a = 1, d = NA) 
str(a)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ d: logi NA
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

a[!is.na(a) & d == "3"] # this returns NAs
#     a  d
# 1: NA NA

a[!is.na(a) & !is.na(d)] # this returns nothing
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,d
```

This one also works:

```
a = data.table(a = 1, d = 4) 
str(a)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ d: num 4
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

a[!is.na(a) & d == "3"]
#     Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,d
```

Looks like if a variable is of logical type it can't be compared to another type and returns NAs.
However, with the dplyr package it seems to work:

```
library(dplyr)

a = data.table(a = 1, d = NA) 
a %>% filter(!is.na(a) & d == "3")
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,d
```

The same with the subset command:

```
subset(a, !is.na(a) & d == "3")
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,d
```